# How to Serialize-Deserialize Dictionary<String, Product> in .net and mongodb?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have this document structure in my MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6249f0df30dfe57eef463997"
    },
    "111-333": [{
        "_id": "",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "iPhone 123",
        "description": "Sample description",
        "price": 100.0,
        "imageUrl": "images/product_images/iphone.jpg",
        "category": "Electronics",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "iPhone 3",
        "description": "Sample description 2",
        "price": 50.0,
        "imageUrl": "images/product_images/iphone.jpg",
        "category": "Electronics",
        "quantity": 1
    }]
}
```

I am trying to read this in C# Model class as follows:

```
    public class Orders
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        [BsonElement("_id")]
        [JsonPropertyName("mongoId")]
        public string? MongoId { get; set; }

        [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.Document)]
        public Dictionary<String, List<Product>> Order;

        public Orders(String MongoId, Dictionary<String, List<Product>> Order)
        {
            this.MongoId = MongoId;
            this.Order = Order;
        }
    }
```

So basically, the "id" is being mapped with "MongoId" and now I want to map the entire dictionary to the variable "Order" but when I try to call the `GET API`, following error is thrown:

```
System.FormatException: Element '111-333' does not match any field or property of class marketplace_services_CSI5112.Models.Orders. at 

MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeClass(BsonDeserializationContext context) at 

MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
```

Can anyone please help with this!!!! I have even tried using `[BsonExtraElements]`but it didn't work for me.

Product model:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace marketplace_services_CSI5112.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        [BsonElement("_id")]
        [JsonPropertyName("mongoId")]
        public string? MongoId { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("id")]
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("name")]
        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("imageUrl")]
        [JsonPropertyName("imageUrl")]
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("description")]
        [JsonPropertyName("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("category")]
        [JsonPropertyName("category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("price")]
        [JsonPropertyName("price")]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("quantity")]
        [JsonPropertyName("quantity")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public Product(String MongoId, int Id, string Name, string Description, double Price, string ImageUrl, string Category, int Quantity)
        {
            this.MongoId = MongoId;
            this.Id = Id;
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Description = Description;
            this.Price = Price;
            this.ImageUrl = ImageUrl;
            this.Category = Category;
            this.Quantity = Quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of MongoDB collection:]

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure if this is possible, however, I solved it by changed the document structure itself. In the existing structure, the `key` was always going to be dynamic so it logically the model won't know how to map it to a specific variable. Instead, I suggest to store them in the proper format and play around with your API return parameters if you want to return the data in a specific format, in this case, it was `Dictionary<String, List<Product>>`.

Updated collection: [image]

Updated model to map these values:

```
public class Orders
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    [JsonPropertyName("mongoId")]
    public string? MongoId { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("id")]
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("products")]
    [JsonPropertyName("products")]
    public List<Product> ProductList;

    public Orders(String MongoId, string Id,  List<Product> ProductList)
    {
        this.MongoId = MongoId;
        this.Id = Id;
        this.ProductList = ProductList;
    }
}
```